# Null pointer exception on click submit

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, input, nullpointerexception

i created a user management (Create, Read, Update, Delete) with Java and sql.
Here is my dao:

```
private static final String UPDATE = "UPDATE user set login_user=?, pwd_user=?, id_role=? where id_user=? ";

@Override
public void update_user(User user) throws DAOException {
    Connection connexion = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        connexion = (Connection) dao_factory.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connexion.prepareStatement(UPDATE);  
        preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getLogin());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getPwd());
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, user.getRole());
        preparedStatement.setLong(4, user.getId_user());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DAOException(e);
    } 

}
```

My jsp for update user:

```
<%
if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
%>
<form method="get" action="client">
   <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" placeholder="login">
        <a href="client?action=update&id=${ user_edit.id_user }" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
   </div>
 </form>
 <% } %>
```

And my servlet:

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");
    if (request.getParameter("action") != null && action.equalsIgnoreCase("view")) {
        request.setAttribute("client", user_dao.find_all());
    }
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        user_dao.delete_user(id);
        request.setAttribute("client", user_dao.find_all());
    }
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        User user = user_dao.getById(id);
        session.setAttribute("user_edit", user);
    } 
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("update")) {
        Long id = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id"));
        String login = request.getParameter("login");
        User user = new User();
        user.setLogin("test_login");
        user.setPwd("test_pwd");
        user.setRole(1);
        user.setId_user(id);
        user_dao.update_user(user);
    }
    else {
        request.setAttribute("client", user_dao.find_all());
    }

    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response);
```

My first problem is, when i click in the button "update", it work. But if i press enter, i have a null pointer exception

Second problem is, If I want to recover login user with `String login = request.getParameter("login");`and `user.setLogin(login);` the login value is null in db.

Thanks a lot

EDIT:
here is stack trace:

```
Avertissement:   StandardWrapperValve[client]: Servlet.service() for servlet `client threw exception`
java.lang.NullPointerException
at egame.servlets.admin.client.processRequest(client.java:53)
at egame.servlets.admin.client.doGet(client.java:94)
```

- line 53 : `if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete"))`.
- line 94 is empty

Comment: What's the stack trace? What have you done to debug it?

Comment: a added the stack. thanks

Answer (score 0):

ResultSet resultSet = null;
It is still null after update user is called.

In any case you are trying to access

the servlet will always call request.setAttribute("client", user_dao.find_all());

Use else if unless you want it to happen only on nonupdate cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML/JSP is wrong. You create a HTML-form but what you say is a "button" is actually just an ***independent*** link. This is the reason of both issues you mention:

1. When you click the link form is not submitted
2. When you press enter, the form is submitted but without data you put in URL

You need to change it to something like

```
<%
if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
%>
<form method="post" action="client">
   <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" placeholder="login">

        <input type="hidden" id="action" value="update" >
        <input type="hidden" id="id"  value="${ user_edit.id_user }" >
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
   </div>
 </form>
 <% } %>
```

Side node: ***NEVER*** use HTTP GET to submit any changes to the server. If you change data on the server, it should be POST (or DELETE, or PUT but not GET).